# Coldfusion Query of Query runtime error, Casting to type NULL is unsupported

Tags: coldfusion

As a proof of concept, I'm trying to convert an array of structs into a query object, so that I can query it using SQL and query of query. I'm able to convert the array of structs into a query object using queryNew():

```
<cfset qTest = queryNew(things)>
```

And I'm finding that I can cfdump it, but I can't query it:

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" dbtype="query">
     SELECT *
     FROM qTest
</cfquery>
```

Because I'm getting this error:

```
Query Of Queries runtime error.
Unsupported Cast Excpetion: Casting to type NULL is unsupported.
```

After Googling this error and seeing issues some others have had, I believe this has to do with the fact that when you create a custom query this way (i.e., supplying only an array of structs to queryNew(), without the column list or data type list), then the query object interprets the struct keys as column names and assumes the appropriate data type.

As an experiment, I included only the first ten structs (or rows, if you like) in the array, fed the array to queryNew(), and had no problems with querying the query. I increased the number of rows until I got up to row 130, and then I got that error message again. No problems if the array had rows only 1-129, but error message when I added row 130. So I thought row 130 must be the problem row. But then, if I include only rows 120-130, I have no problems. If I include only rows 100-130, no problems. But if I include rows 90-130, I get the error message again.

So I figure that as I increased the number of rows, eventually CF decides to assign a different datatype, one that triggers that "casting to type NULL is unsupported" when row 130 is included. The obvious workaround would normally be to include the column list and datatype list as arguments in queryNew(), but that's impractical in my case for a couple of reasons. One, it's a very long column list (62). Two, that's very inflexible; this array of structs is ultimately coming from data from an API, and if the column list were ever to change at all, my code would break.

So what I'm wondering is if there's any other way to prevent that "Casting to type NULL is unsupported" error. Or, if there's a way to output what data types CF is assigning to each column. Else, if I can't work with this data in query format using SQL, it's going to be very cumbersome having to loop through arrays of structs to find and pull out the data I want. Seems that's the whole reason why Adobe enhanced queryNew() to be able to accept an array of structs as an argument in the first place.

I would include some sample data, but the query has 62 columns. I'm hoping this is a known issue with a known workaround -- thanks.

Comment: Regarding, `Or, if there's a way to output what data types CF is assigning to each column. `, the `metainfo` attribute of the `cfdump` tag might help.

Comment: Why bother jumping through hoops? You can use the various array functions to iterate, search and filter the array.

Answer (score 2):

As @EddieLotter pointed out, there are a number of ways to address this with Array functions alone. For example, here's `ArrayFilter` which has existed since ACF 10:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayfilter.html

Code from their example:

```
  <cfscript>
        superheroes=[
              {"name":"Iron Man","member":"Avengers"},
              {"name":"Wonder Woman","member":"Justice League"},
              {"name":"Hulk","member":"Avengers"},
              {"name":"Thor","member":"Avengers"},
              {"name":"Aquaman","member":"Justice League"}
        ];
        avengers=ArrayFilter(superheroes,function(item){
              return item.member=="Avengers";
        });
        writeDump(avengers);
  </cfscript>
```

This outputs the three elements containing the key `member` with the value `Avengers`. Just use `<cfloop type="array">` instead of `<cfquery>`.